# how to print 2 dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays

I created a boolean 2 dimensional array and try to print "A"(Config.ALIVE) for true and "."(Config.DEAD)for false by invoking another method. But my code only prints out A. Can anyone tell me why?
here is my code

```
public static void initializeGlider(boolean[][] world) {
        for (int row = 0; row < Config.WORLD_ROWS; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < Config.WORLD_COLUMNS; column++) {
                if (row==1&&column==1)
                    world[row][column] = true;
                 if (row==2&&column==2)
                     world[row][column] = true;
                if (row==2&&column==3)
                     world[row][column] = true;
                if (row==3&&column==1)
                     world[row][column] = true;
                 if (row==3&&column==2)
                    world[row][column] = true;
                else
                    world[row][column] = false;
            }
        }

        printWorld("Glider",world,0);
    }
        public static void printWorld(String patternName, boolean[][] world,
            int generationNum) {
        int row = 0;
        int column = 0;
        for (row = 0; row < Config.WORLD_ROWS; row++) {
            // for each column in the world
            for (column = 0; column < Config.WORLD_COLUMNS; column++) {
                // if the cell is alive
                if (world[row][column] = true)
                    System.out.print(Config.ALIVE);
                // otherwise if the cell is dead.
                if (world[row][column] = false)
                    System.out.print(Config.DEAD);


                // print out the number of cells alive.
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your code in here

```
 if (world[row][column] = true)
     System.out.print(Config.ALIVE);
 // otherwise if the cell is dead.
 if (world[row][column] = false)
    System.out.print(Config.DEAD);
```

I think it will be

```
if (world[row][column] == true)
      System.out.print(Config.ALIVE);
 // otherwise if the cell is dead.
 if (world[row][column] == false)
      System.out.print(Config.DEAD);
```